# What is the relationship between input value and dictionary

Tags: python, neural-network, conv-neural-network

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
    
x = np.random.randn(1000,100)
node_num = 100
hidden_layer_size = 5
activations = {}

for i in range(hidden_layer_size)
    if i != 0:
        x = activations[i-1]

    w = np.random.randn(node_num, node_num)*1
    a = np.dot(x,w)
    z = sigmoid(a)
    activations[i] = z
```

I can't figure out what means that `for i in range(hidden_layer_size) ~~ x = activations[i-1]` statements. I understand that `x` is input and `activations` dictionary is to keep track of the result of each hidden layer. I wonder what relationship is between `x` and `activations` dictionary through the code and why it is needed.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong.  The last 4 lines need to be indented so they are part of the loop.  With that, you run your `sigmoid` computation once with the random `x`, and each successive loop uses the previous result.  I'll fix the code to show you.

Comment: So, you will get 5 entries in `activations`, each with the result of cycle #i.

Comment: We can't answer "what is the purpose" of chunk of the code when there is no informatiopn about what this code is supposed to do. Right now it is just a loop that creates a random neural net, does not store its parameters, but stores activation at each layer in activations dict (it could as well just be a list). That's all that it does

Comment: @TimRoberts Appreciate for correction first of all, I understand 'activations' directory will save the previous result as it is defined 'activations[i] = z' at the end of the code. Then why that 'if' sentences is needed? What is 'x = activations[i-1]' sentence supposed to mean?

Comment: That fetches the value from the previous pass.  Each new record is based on the contents of the previous record.  They probably should have used a list and written `activations[-1]` here.  Since there is no "previous record" on the very first pass, that action is skipped when `i == 0`, and `x` will have the random numbers from above.